# How to insert facebook audience network ad on AMP page?

Tags: amp-html

AMP pages doesn't allow javascript and the `<amp-ad>` tag does not support Facebook Audience network, what can I do to insert a facebook audience network ad?

Comment: Please show us what you have done so far to solve your problem,

Comment: @legrandviking AMP is very limited at this stage, I tried using an amp-iframe but it requires me to have https, which I don't have because is just a blog. I could write my own js plugin but I lack the ability. And the documentation says amp-iframe is not recommended for ads.

Comment: HTTPS is a prereq. Get Dropbox and use /Public - which is HTTPS. Then test your blogpost there. But you're not gonna get much more help unless you follow @legrandviking advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can ask (open a issue) on [Githib](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/ads/README.md) to support Facebook Audience network, but i am not familar with this. Maybe the network self must ask for support.

Comment: yes, after checking on the docs, I think they have to add support by themselves.