# how to integrate facebook audience network in google accelerated mobile pages

Tags: amp-html, facebook-audience-network, facebook-instant-articles, accelerated-mobile-page

I am searching on how to monetize my blog with Facebook Audience Network (FAN)..
i know that normal blog (non AMP) can use FAN, but does AMP have support for the FAN?

i confuse because,,

while searching on the web..
i found this link

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instant-articles/other-formats#instant-articles-to-amp

from the link, it talk about instant article ad which obviously i think it is FAN..
but

i didn't found FAN to be supported for AMPHTML_ads in here
https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-ad#supported-ad-networks

can someone clarify?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may refer with this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38077536/how-to-insert-facebook-audience-network-ad-on-amp-page?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) regarding FAN AMP pages. It suggested to check the [Github page](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/ads/README.md) to support Facebook Audience network. The guide provides details for ad networks to create an amp-ad integration for their network.